# ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-root' not found. Skipping fsck

Tags: arch-linux

I used the lvm on luks encrytion method.

I was booted to this

```
Starting version 241.7-2-arch
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-root' not found. Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]# _
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't set up any hooks for opening the LUKS partition. The arch wiki has a [good guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS) on setting this up

Answer (score 2):

```
# mount /dev/MyVolGroup/root /mnt
# mkdir /mnt/home
# mount /dev/MyVolGroup/home /mnt/home
# swapon /dev/MyVolGroup/swap

# mkdir /mnt/hostlvm
# mount --bind /run/lvm /mnt/hostlvm
# arch-chroot /mnt
# ln -s /hostlvm /run/lvm
```

I added:
cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:cryptlvm root=/dev/MyVolGroup/root

within the Double quotes of 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" and 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
in

/etc/default/grub

to get:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:cryptlvm root=/dev/MyVolGroup/root"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:cryptlvm root=/dev/MyVolGroup/root"
```

The device-UUID is something you need to get with:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

you put the UUID where device-UUID showed up before.

Before these I did

```
arch-chroot /mnt
```

Don't regenerate the grub config yet.
I regenerated the grub config.(this was the wrong time to do it)

I reinstalled linux with
pacman -S linux

Make sure the hoods are right in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf go to lvm on luks
in the archlinux wiki to see them.

Then I ran

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

I exited arch-chroot by using the command exit.

```
exit
```

I did this

```
mkdir /mnt/hostlvm
mount --bind /run/lvm /mnt/hostlvm
arch-chroot /mnt
ln -s /hostlvm /run/lvm
```

then I ran

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I exited out of arch-chroot the rebooted with

```
exit
```

then

```
reboot
```

And it worked after that.

Comment: if I wanna do `$ mount /dev/MyVolGroup/root /mnt` like you did, it would look like `mount /dev/mapper/crypred_device/root /mnt`  but it's not possible with the root..